# Poco C++ libraries send an asynchronous server reply

Tags: c++, poco, poco-libraries

Are there any users of the Poco C++ libraries who know of a way to send an asynchronous reply to a server request? Consider the code:

```
void handler::handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest &request, HTTPServerResponse &response)
{
   Poco::Util::Application::instance().logger().information("Got A Request");
   Poco::Util::Application::instance().logger().information("Sending response");
   response.setStatusAndReason(HTTPResponse::HTTP_OK);
   response.send();
   //Do some more processing, but allow for the response to actually be sent to the client.
   auto& stream = request.stream().
   //Do some processing on the data POSTd with the request
}
```

In the above code, the HTTP reply initiated by response.send(), is not received by the client (in the case cURL) until the handleRequest method returns.

Comment: may be something is received . you can't know because curl is waiting to the end of operation before display something. while socket is open it's silent.i think it's like that. if you tune it to display header may be it'll do right away

Comment: unfortunately the behavior is the same across different clients. curl, wget, browsers, and python requests module

Comment: it should be the same